# SQL Server Always Encrypted - Certificate with thumbprint 'xyz' not found in certificate store 'My' in certificate location 'CurrentUser'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, always-encrypted

**Environment**

- Windows Server 2016
- SQL Server 2016 (13.0.6404.1 - latest CU as of 16th Dec 2021)
- ASP.NET Web Forms / .NET framework 4.8
- IIS 10
- 2x SQL Server instances on two machines set up in an availability
  group
- 2x web servers that are load balanced

I'm quite baffled by this. I've enabled Always Encrypted on our production servers, encrypted some columns after creating the master and column keys, and exported the generated certificate from the certificate store. I imported this to the two web server's "local computer\certificates" store and granted read access to the certificate's private key for the user that our application pool authorizes (from certificate manager, local computer->personal->certificates -> right click on always encrypted certificate -> all tasks -> manage private keys and granted access here)
No problems here, my web application can read and write to the encrypted columns.

However, on our test environment which is running SQL Server 2017 (14.0.3421.10 - latest CU as of 16th Dec 2021), I've followed the exact process as above, but am encountering the exception in the title - `Certificate with thumbprint 'XYZ' not found in certificate store 'My' in certificate location 'CurrentUser'. Verify the certificate path in the column master key definition in the database is correct, and the certificate has been imported correctly into the certificate location/store. Parameter name: masterKeyPath`

As a test, I changed the website's connection string to point to the production server (they're on the same network) and imported the 'always encrypted' certificate from production, and granted access to the certificate for the application pool user. This works with no problem.

I was running SQL 2017 v 14.0.3370.1 (released 12th Jan 2021) before posting this question but I noticed I was a few Culmative Updates behind, so I've just upgraded the instance to the latest version - but looking through the release notes of the 5 new versions released since then, there is no reference to Always Encrypted. The error still happens after the upgrade, anyway.

I have `Column Encryption Setting=enabled` in the connection string - if I remove this, the exception changes - `'Conversion from type 'Byte()' to type 'String' is not valid`. -- which indicates that the client-side encryption is failing.

I also tried creating a new certificate and new master/column keys and re-encrypting the columns using these (after exporting the new certificate over to the webserver) - but to no avail, still getting the 'certificate not found' error. I've also tried to grant access to 'EVERYONE' for the certificate too - but the same exception here.

I'm at a bit of a loss here as the only difference between the 2 is the version of SQL server - production being 2016 and test being 2017

Comment: Just trying to understand: you imported the certificate into the *client* machine's store? And did you give permissions on the private key (as well as the certificate) to the user? Are you sure the user you are granting permissions is the correct user (should be the one the App Pool is using)

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, yup - that's correct - on the client store - the test web server. I followed the exact same procedure that I done on the production web servers, and also when "hooking up" the test web server to communicate with the production DB.

Comment: OK which user did you add permissions for? And did you add permissions on the private key?

Comment: Yup, the user I've assigned the App Pool to authorise as. I followed the exact same procedure for connecting to the production DB from my test server (export cert from produ DB onto test web server, assigned permissions to key for that user, changed connection string to point to production DB) and I could read the encrypted data with no problems. It's baffling why it's not working! Like I said in the question, I even started again with a new certificate and master/column keys to no avail